# How to a return business object from factory using http get in angularjs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am new to AngularJs. Could anyone help to write a factory using **http** service in angularJS so that the factory returns me a business object instead of promise or assigning value to the scope variable on success. I researched so many articles in the web, but all are using either callback function or by returning promises from the http service. 
**Requirement :** Let's say XMLtoJsonService is my factory which converts xml to json from the local folder. factory should be return business object so that in my controller I should be able to use in following way

```
    //controller 
    var obj = XMLtoJsonService.MethodName(); 

**(No promises or callback function should be used in controller)** 
/*******service code****************/

    App.factory('XmlToJsonSvc',
            [ '$http', function($http) {
                return {
                    get : function(path, callback) {
                        $http.get(path, {
                            transformResponse : function(data) {
                                // convert the data to JSON and provide
                                // it to the success function below
                                var x2js = new X2JS();
                                var json = x2js.xml_str2json(data);
                                return json;
                            }
                        }).success(function(data, status) {
                            //console.log('Sucess');

                            callback(data);
                        })
                    }
                }
    } ]);

/*********Controller Code **********/
var setData = function(data) {

            return new Menus(data);

            debugger
        }
        var path = "Configs/Config.xml";
        XmlToJsonSvc.get(path, setData);
```

//This code is working fine 
//But my requirement is to convert this code so that in my controller it should   //like var obj =  XmlToJsonSvc.get(path) 
//obj should have json object which i ll be using another service

Comment: So you plan on blocking the entire browser pending the http response?

Comment: NO But I want to use a service which can return me a business object. I am initializing object based on the json object which i return from the service.

Comment: You should put promise resolving in your service then. It might work.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!--In this funcion calling factory function restCall() from controller.
before that i have assigned a already created factory object to a scope variable in controller
.So whenever factory varaible updates,that update will be available to controller automatically.
Some kind of 2-way binding method from factory object-->


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"  ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  {{obj.data1}}
  
  <button ng-click="clickFn()">Clicking this will call service</button>

<script>

    (function() {
      var app = angular.module("app",[])
      
      .controller("myCtrl",function(myFactory,$scope){
        
        $scope.obj = myFactory.bObject;
        
        $scope.clickFn  = function(){
          myFactory.restCall();
        }
        
         
      }).factory("myFactory",function($timeout){
        
        var bObject = {
          data1 :null
        };

        function restCall(){
          $timeout(function(){
            bObject.data1 = bObject.data1 ? false : true ;
          },1000);
        }
        
        var service = {
          bObject : bObject,
          restCall : restCall,
        }
        return service;
        
      });
    }());

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks Nikhil for your respnse. I need some like this I have a factory App.factory('XmlToJsonSvc',
  [ '$http', function($http) {
   return {
    get : function(path, callback) {
     $http.get(path, {
      transformResponse : function(data) {
       // convert the data to JSON and provide
       // it to the success function below
       var x2js = new X2JS();
       var json = x2js.xml_str2json(data);
       return json;
      }
     }).success(function(data, status) {
      //console.log('Sucess');

      callback(data);
     }) 
   }} ]); 
I need to modify this service

Comment: but here you mentioned a callback

Comment: U can use anything or any logic in the factory but not in the controller.U can write any number of services or wrapper functions on top this but  In controller I should be using like var obj = Xmlsercvice.MethodName().

Comment: so methodName() would block for the duration of the http call?

Comment: Here i am not using any promise.But result will be updated to controller.

Comment: @Nikhil thanks for your response man. But my use case is different I guess. Could you please check my edited code.

Comment: the edited code is perfect imo :) as in, it cannot be improved

Comment: @PeterGelderbloem there should be some work around I feel

Comment: callbacks and promises are standard in javascript.

Comment: @PeterGelderbloem Is there any other way where I can create model object on load by reading the config xml?